# In Silverlight, is it possible to bind buttons to a command from a different class?

Tags: silverlight

In Silverlight, if  the datacontext of the userControl inn Xaml is Class A, can a button in the  bind to a command in a different class (lets say class B)?

Thanks.

Comment: this is standard procedure in MVVM, where you bind the Button to a command in the view  model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done. there are several ways:

1. You could assign the DataContext of the button to an instance of class B.
2. You could add an instance of class to the Resources of the button (or one of the button's parents) and point the binding to a StaticResource
3. Add a property of type B to class A and bind the Command of the button to that property of class A.

I prefer none of these option but if I have to chose I pick #3. #1 and #2 cause too much confusion. The best solution IMHO is to add the Command to class A because that is much more clear and fits a MVVM state of mind

Answer (score 1):

In a word, yes.  However, your Class A (datacontext) will need access to an instance of Class B and expose it publicly (or expose whatever it is you want to bind to--like a delegate).

In general, anything you bind to in XAML requires that the binding path is reachable through your DataContext.